# How to know particular shortcut is added in our shortcuts app or not using our iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, shortcut, sirishortcuts

I run the shortcuts with the x-callback url given below code:

```
let url = URL(string: "shortcuts://x-callback-url/run-shortcut?name=Airplane&x-success=shortcutsdemo://")
UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

When I open the URL in `UIApplication.shared.open`, it runs the shortcut and after its done, return back to our iOS app.

**My question** is if my shortcut is not added in shortcuts app, how I manage?

Is there any way to first find our shortcut is added or not in shortcuts app and then we run the shortcut.

Like :

```
if (Shortcut.isInstalled) {
    let url = URL(string: "shortcuts://x-callback-url/run-shortcut?name=Airplane&x-success=shortcutsdemo://")
    UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
   print("Not installed")
}
```

**Summary :**
If the shortcut is added in our shortcuts app, Then it's run the shortcuts using our iOS app. Otherwise its not run. and give an error for that shortcut.

Comment: What you min with shortcut is installed in our shortcut app? I guess that you are mixing concepts between Shortcuts and url-scheme

Comment: I want to know shortcut is installed in our shortcuts app or not ?

Answer (score -1):

I think you will need to use `func canOpenURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool`

```
let url = URL(string: "shortcuts://x-callback-url/run-shortcut?name=Airplane&x-success=shortcutsdemo://")

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(ur!l) {

        print("Short uts is installed")
    } else {

        print("Shortcuts not installed")
    }
```

I am not 100% sure, but I think it redirects you automatically to appstore if you don't have it, check that out.

Comment: Its check that shortcuts app is installed in iPhone or not. I want to know particular shortcut in added in shortcuts app or not.

Comment: This does not work. The condition is always true, even when the Shortcuts app is not installed.